# Micrometers fails to save metrics to elasticsearch as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, doc]

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, micrometer

I am trying to implement Micrometer Elasticsearch registry and I am getting the following error

```
      {
    "took": 158,
    "errors": true,
    "items": [
      {
        "index": {
          "_index": "metrics-2019-11",
          "_type": "doc",
          "_id": "PDzhNm4BiJBtovrbDFDF",
          "status": 400,
          "error": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [metrics--2019-11] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, doc]"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "index": {
          "_index": "metrics--2019-11",
          "_type": "doc",
          "_id": "PTzhNm4BiJBtovrbDFDF",
          "status": 400,
          "error": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [metrics--2019-11] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, doc]"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have to say that I do not understand the error so much, is micrometer trying to push the same doc to 2 different keys (doc and _doc)?

I do not see in the documentation anything about the type of document or its key or anything thats related

as well, The indices have not been created beforehand, I let micrometer create them, so how is this not working.

Elasticsearch 7.4.2

Micrometer 1.2.1

Spring boot 2.1.2

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have several spring applications publishing metrics to elasticsearch and only one of those is facing this problem.

Comment: Yep, I did, don't remember how though, it was something stupid in the configuration. to bad I didn't come back to update the question

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when using incompatible versions of the `spring-boot-gradle-plugin` and the `mavenBom`.

For example, I had in my build.gradle file the following:

```
buildscript {
...
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.2.5.RELEASE"
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Greenwich.SR1"
    }
}
```

But `2.2.5.RELEASE` and `Greenwich.SR1` are not in the same [release trains](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#release-trains). Changing the "Bom" version to `Hoxton.SR1` fixed the issue.

Even if you're not using gradle, the problem is probably because of incompatible dependency versions.